# Export Mathematica equations to Matlab

Tags: matlab, converters, wolfram-mathematica

I did some symbolic calculations in Mathematica and want to transfer the result to MATLAB, i.e. export the output of Mathematica calculations to valid MATLAB syntax.

There is a [question on mathematica.stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14035/is-it-possible-to-export-the-equations-from-mathematica-to-matlab) which asks the same thing, but the accepted answer is too limited for what I want. Specifically, the [`ToMatlab`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) package was suggested.

I need a similar package, which can doesn't share the same flaws, like not handling `atan2`.

So, does anybody know a working alternative to the `ToMatlab` package?

Comment: From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking us to recommend or find a software library or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* You may be better asking this question back on mathematica.stackexchange, where there are obviously people willing to answer (as evidenced by your linked question)

Comment: Okidoki, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: 'ToMatLab' is an open-source Mathematica package, which could be brought up-to-date.  The OP is asking for any Mathematica code/package that could export to Matlab.  Such a package could be posted here and would not necessarily be an off-site resource.

Comment: Answered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166162/363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine 'ToMatLab.m' you will see the simple literal conversions for trig functions.  Just add your function and see if it works.

```
ToMatlabaux[Sin] = "sin"
ToMatlabaux[Cos] = "cos"
ToMatlabaux[Tan] = "tan"
ToMatlabaux[Cot] = "cot"
```

The `ToMatLab` package is actually quite a small piece of code.

Comment: Thanks. FYI: The related post on mathematica.stackexchange is located [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166163/mathematica-to-matlab?noredirect=1#comment439047_166163)

Comment: be aware mathematica's two arg inverse tangent has the arguments in the reverse order ( `x,y` vs `y,x` ) of matlab and most other common languages.  mathematica also does not have a separate 2-argument function, it is `ArcTan[y/x]` or `ArcTan[x,y]`